# Find the direction of motion?

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion, direction, cmmotionmanager

I have an image(floor plan) where i pinned my current position. with `CMPedometer` I am able to find the number of steps moved but couldn't find the direction in which i am moving.

```
if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){

    self.pedoMeter.startUpdates(from: midnightOfToday) { (data: CMPedometerData?, error) -> Void in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            if(error == nil) {
                self.stepsLabel.text = "Moved \(data!.numberOfSteps) steps"
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Is there any way of finding the direction i am moving (relevant to my point OR to E,W,S,N ) ?

Comment: See this [change pin direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198165/change-pin-direction-in-ios-map/41224068#41224068) if it helps.

Comment: I guess CLLocationManager heading could be used to get the direction.

Answer (score 0):

[CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmotionmanager) provides you API to work with Magnetometer.

It should be use to determine heading (North).