# iOS How to show in which direction user are going Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit, apple-maps

I am using apple maps in my application and I want to show in which direction the user is facing. Currently in my app it's showing like:
[image]

But i want:

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Pin direction in iOS Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198165/change-pin-direction-in-ios-map)

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Comment: Update pictures, what i want

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/40808645/1740354

Comment: Somebody have, simple solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Setting > Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Compass Calibration > Enable
You will be able to see the direction the user is facing.

You can take the user to the GPS Settings by doing.

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL.init(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))
```

You can prompt the user to enable the compass calibration, but there is no way you can set it without user interaction.

Comment: I my Google map and apple map it's work, but in my map it's not work

Comment: Are you using Google Maps SDK or Apple Maps?

Comment: You mean in my app, i user Apple Maps